# Flutter Late variable throwing LateInitializationError even after assigning a value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have variable `selectedLocale` which is set as Late in the class, and the variable is assigned to a value during its init method which is called from other class.

There is another get method which is returning the variable after the value is assigned, but even after assigning the value in the init method, while the code comes to get method it says the variable is not initialised. I'm not understanding the reason for this behaviour.

Language change provider.

```
@lazySingleton
class LanguageChangeProvider with ChangeNotifier {

  late Locale selectedLocale;

  void init(String _locale) {
    selectedLocale = Locale(_locale); // Value assigned to variable here
  }

  Locale get currentLocale {
   return selectedLocale; //Not initialised exception thrown here
  } 

  void changeLocale(String _locale) {  
    selectedLocale = Locale(_locale);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

currentLocale get method being set in main.dart file.

```
  MaterialApp buildApp(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp.router(

        locale: Provider.of<LanguageChangeProvider>(context, listen: true).currentLocale, // Getting set here
        restorationScopeId: 'app',
        localizationsDelegates: const [
          Localization.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ]
      );
```

Service where the value is being set from:

```
 abstract class Service {
    
      Future<void> init();
    }
   
    class ServiceImpl implements Service {
      ServiceImpl(this.localProvider);
    
      final LanguageChangeProvider localProvider;
    
      @override
      Future<void> init() async {
            await localProvider.init(‘en’);
          } 
     }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `init()` before `currentLocale`?

Comment: I'm sure, I have added screenshots on the sequence for better understanding

Comment: Can you put more code about how you using it? Including how you initialize and how you access it.

Comment: My only guess is you're not actually using a `Singleton` for both call. include the call sites in the question if possible.

Comment: @MohamedMohsin, I guess you might be right. I have updated the question as per your request.

Comment: Are you using `GetIt` with this `Provider`? if so make sure you're only using a single `GetIt` instance inside it (across all calls) so the `@lazySingleton` annotation is respected. Also, are you using `Provider` with `Service`?

Answer (score 1):

Update: A quick thing I follow cases like this making data nullable(when It is not possible to init data from constructor), So that I can check on read-time.

In your case, I will do like
`Locale? selectedLocale;` and while reading, check null.

As you described, you're assigning value before reading. Then the only thing is missing here, to notify the listener.

```dart
  void init(String _locale) {
    selectedLocale = Locale(_locale);  
     notifyListeners(); // this
  }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to help. The get method currentLocale gets called from the main.dart for the first time without using notifyListerns(). But anyway, even after adding that its still the same. I have added 2 screenshots in the origin post for better understanding

Comment: Can you include the use cases

Comment: I have updated the question for usecases. Looks like I'm updating the variable from a different instance and trying to get the value from different instance. Is there a way to handle it?

Comment: I think you are looking for singleton and `Future<void> init() async` being future, it takes time and won't have value on 1st build.